# scan barcode in cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-cli

When i adding ZXing library then this code works for android But it cannot work in iOS. getting error 'ERROR: Plugin 'BarcodeScanner' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml. '

```
$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
        alert(imageData.text);
        console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
        console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
    }, function(error) {
       console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
    })
}
```

Comment: use https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner plugin for scan

Comment: same  ERROR: Plugin 'BarcodeScanner' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

Comment: remove your old scanner plugin, do **cordova ios clean** , install above link plugin barcode scanner plugin and follow example of above plugin

Comment: i didn't use above plugin ever but it has almost 900 star so it should work fine.

Comment: and yes you have to change code for scan cording to new plugin example

Comment: i m create new project and add this plugin but getting same error. i don't understand CDVPlugin not found.

Comment: did you tried in android?

Comment: yes in android it works

Comment: your device ios version?

Comment: try with latest plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

Comment: version is 10.0.2

Comment: try last commented link of plugin..